# Delete Rows Based on Visible Range In Another Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets, sheet1 and sheet2.  Since there are common rows in both sheets, I want to delete rows in sheet1 that can be found in sheet2.  I only want rows in sheet 1 to be deleted for a columns that have the criteria "Y".  I I filtered the column using criteria Y in sheet2 and selected the range as visible range.  So the deletion of rows in sheet1 should be based on the visible range in sheet2.  However, the deletion of rows in sheet1 is deleting every occurrence as per sheet2, not as per the visible range. I have the below code but it's not working.  Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

```
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Y"
End With

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
            If IsNumeric(Application.Match(.Range("A" & i).Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), 0)) Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: So if the rows 1,3 and 5 are the only visible ones in Sheet2, you want those same rows deleted in Sheet1?

Comment: Do both files have the same rows structure? I mean the same number of rows, located in the same position?

Comment: No, both files have rows that are randomly listed.  The rows to be deleted in sheet1 will be based on 2 criteria in sheet2.  One criteria is having value in a column equal to Yes, and the other criteria is having value in a column equal to a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirements correctly, this code will work.

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim data As Range
    Set data = .Range("B1:B" & lastRow)

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    data.AutoFilter 1, "Y"

    Dim deleteRows As Range
    Set deleteRows = data.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

End With

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(deleteRows.Address).EntireRow.Delete
```

To remove the values in sheet1 that are in the sheet2 filtered data do this

```
Dim d as Range
For each d in deleteRows

    Dim found as Range
    Set found = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1).Find(d.Value,lookat:=xlWhole)

    If not found is Nothing Then

        Dim removeFrom1 as Range
        If removeFrom1 is Nothing Then
            set removeFrom1 = found
        else
            set removeFrom1 = Union(removeFrom1,found)
        end If

    End If

Next

removeFrom1.entirerow.delete
```

Comment: That's great @SJL. If you mark it as answered, it will help others in the future.

Comment: I realized the code delete based on address.  It will work perfectly if rows in both sheets are in the same order.  After filtering in sheet2 and if I want to delete rows in sheet1 as per the unique identifier in sheet 2, how would I do it?  Thanks.

Comment: it didn't work.  It's not going into the if not found is nothing then loop.

Comment: please debug the code and see *why* it's not finding the cell value you expect. I don't have your data and can't investigate. I also have a priority project that needs to be addressed. @SJL

Comment: Alirght.  Thanks.